# Replace tag [parse.com] with [parse-platform]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [parse.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parse.com) should be replaced with [parse-platform](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parse-platform) analogous to a similar [renaming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364789/should-we-make-tag-parse-com-a-synonym-of-parse-server) that was done on Stack Overflow.

This tag request is part of the Parse Community's effort to maintain Parse Platform related tags on Stack Exchange, as described [here](https://community.parseplatform.org/t/parse-related-stackexchange-tags).

Comment: considering that there is only 18 questions and the newest question is from over three years ago, I'd suggest just editing the tags on these questions and suggesting a synonym.

Comment: @Vogel612 I cannot do that because I don’t have edit privileges on CR.

Comment: Correction, I should say I don’t have the rights to create a new tag. I can edit the questions, but they all need to be peer reviewed. If there is a way to prevent creating 18 reviews and using many people’s time to review them, I’d suggest for a mod to do this with less effort, if possible.

Comment: Don't worry, we'll take care of it. I'll do the edits if you take care of synonymization @Vogel612

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has now been done through edits by Mast and the moderator tools for tag handling :)